# is there a simple way to create a nested dropdown in ReactJS without crazy amounts of state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code works but I feel like there's a way to do this without declaring a ton of state.

When the nav is clicked, it opens all SectionHeaders, and when one of those SectionHeaders is clicked, it opens the SubSections (only one SubSection allowed to be opened at once)

isFilterOpen

[image: isFilterOpen]

Open but subs closed

[image: Open but subs closed]

One sub open (only one at a time, they toggle)

[image: One sub open]

Right now, my code looks like this:

```js
class MobileFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFilterOpen: false,
      isSectionOpen: {
        Business: false,
        Resource: false,
        Need: false,
        Implementation: false,
        Type: false,
        Foundations: false,
        Advantage: false,
        Advanced: false,
        Catalyst: false,
        Team: false,
      },
    };
    this.filterBar = React.createRef();
  }

  handleFilterClick = () => {
    const {
      isFilterOpen
    } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      isFilterOpen: !isFilterOpen,
    });
  };

  handleSectionClick = title => {
    let selectedSection = title;
    if (title.split(' ').length > 1) {
      selectedSection = title.split(' ')[0]; // eslint-disable-line
    }

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newState = {};
      Object.keys(prevState.isSectionOpen).forEach(key => {
        newState[key] = false;
      });
      newState[selectedSection] = !prevState.isSectionOpen[selectedSection];
      return {
        ...prevState,
        isSectionOpen: {
          ...newState,
        },
      };
    });
  };

 render() {
    const { isFilterOpen } = this.state;
    const {
      need = '',
      implementation = '',
      type = '',
      customerStoriesURL = '',
      vertical,
    } = this.props;
    const filterClasses = isFilterOpen
      ? 'showMobileSections'
      : 'hideMobileSections';
    const wrapperClass = isFilterOpen
      ? 'mobileFilterWrapperActive'
      : 'mobileFilterWrapper';
    const filterData = this.getData(vertical);

    if (vertical === 'services') {
      return (
        <div className="filterBarMobile" ref={this.filterBar}>
          <div className="mobileFilterWrapperContainer">
            <div className={wrapperClass}>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.handleFilterClick}
                className="filterHead"
              >
                Navigate Hub
              </button>
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections('Foundations', filterData.Foundations)}
              </div>
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections('Advantage', filterData.Advantage)}
              </div>
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections('Advanced', filterData.Advanced)}
              </div>
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections('Catalyst', filterData.Catalyst)}
              </div>
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections(
                  'Team Edition',
                  filterData['Team Edition'],
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="filterBarMobile" ref={this.filterBar}>
        <div className="mobileFilterWrapperContainer">
          <div className={wrapperClass}>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={this.handleFilterClick}
              className="filterHead"
            >
              Navigate Hub
            </button>
            <div className={filterClasses}>
              {this.renderSections(need, filterData.need)}
            </div>
            {implementation ? (
              <div className={filterClasses}>
                {this.renderSections(implementation, filterData.implementation)}
              </div>
            ) : null}
            <div className={filterClasses}>
              {this.renderSections(type, filterData.type)}
            </div>
            <div className={filterClasses}>
              <div className="sectionTab">
                <Link className="sectionLabel" to={customerStoriesURL}>
                  Customer Stories
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MobileFilter;
```

As you can see, there's way too much state going on -- there as to be a way to make this more founded on the data / props that are coming in and not in a way that requires me listing out all of the SubSections as a nested state.

Any ideas would help. Thanks!

Comment: maybe i can use the positioning of each li in the array to determine what's open

Comment: looking into Object.values() on the parent class to gain access to an all items, so instead of naming them in state, i can determine if their index is active and only store that index in state?

Comment: looking into something like e.currentTarget.indexOf(e.target) -- doesn't seem to work i'll keep digging (trying to get the index of targeted item from parent array, push that val into the state and use it to identify which sub nav is active

Answer (score 1):

i think i've found the solution. i needed to start from scratch. here's what i have:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import Search from '../Search';
import { businessData } from './filterData';
import './newFilter.less';

class NewFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      openSubSection: '',
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    if (!isOpen) {
      this.setState({
        openSubSection: '',
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !isOpen,
    });
  };

  handleSubClick = (e, title) => {
    const { openSubSection } = this.state;
    if (openSubSection === title) {
      this.setState({
        openSubSection: '',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        openSubSection: title,
      });
    }
  };

  // renderLinks = sublevels => sublevels.map(({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>);
  renderLinks = sublevels =>
    sublevels.map(({ url_slug, title }) => {
      if (!url_slug) {
        return (
          <div className="sectionLabelSub" key={title}>
            {title}
          </div>
        );
      }
      return (
        <Link
          className="mobileSubLinks"
          key={url_slug}
          to={`/${url_slug}/`}
          style={{ display: 'block' }}
        >
          {title}
        </Link>
      );
    });

  renderSection = section => {
    const { isOpen, openSubSection } = this.state;
    const { title, sublevels } = section;

    let sectionClass = 'hideMobileSections';
    let sectionOpen = 'sectionTabClosed';
    let subSectionClass = 'hideMobileContent';
    let arrowClass = 'arrow arrow--active';

    if (isOpen) {
      sectionClass = 'showMobileSections';
    }

    if (openSubSection === title) {
      subSectionClass = 'showMobileContent';
      sectionOpen = 'sectionTabOpen';
      arrowClass = 'arrow';
    }
    // const sectionClass = isOpen ? 'section__open' : 'section__closed';
    return (
      <div className={sectionClass}>
        <button
          onClick={e => this.handleSubClick(e, title)}
          type="button"
          key={title}
          className={sectionOpen}
        >
          <button type="button" className="sectionLabel">
            {title}
          </button>
          <div className={arrowClass} />
        </button>
        <div className={subSectionClass} role="button" tabIndex="0">
          {this.renderLinks(sublevels)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderSections = sections =>
    sections.map(section => this.renderSection(section));

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    const { navTitle, sections } = businessData;

    let wrapperClass = 'mobileFilterWrapper';

    if (isOpen) {
      wrapperClass = 'mobileFilterWrapperActive';
    }
    return (
      <div className="filterBarMobile" ref={this.filterBar}>
        <Search vertical='business' />
        <div className="mobileFilterWrapperContainer">
          <div className={wrapperClass}>
            <button
              onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
              type="button"
              className="filterHead"
            >
              {navTitle}
            </button>
            {this.renderSections(sections)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewFilter;
```

basically i let the data inform the components, pass in the title to the button and the click event, and then the class looks to see if the title from the data matches the title (string) attached to the state